# Is there a way to return the information from 'viewlsts.aspx' like Allitems.aspx?

Tags: web-services, guid

In the Allitems.aspx there is the CTX.listName which houses the GUID of the list.
what I'm looking for is the GUID for the /_layouts/viewlsts.aspx

is this even possible?

Comment: viewlists.aspx is a generic system page (as is everything under /_layouts/) and does not have a guid.  Can you elaborate on what you are attempting to do?

Comment: Pretty much on the Viewlsts.aspx page we have a systemp list. (I'm not sure if that's a standard SP list) in the _layouts/viewlsts.aspx this list is showing to have like 90 entries.  But when you open it, it shows 0 because of the way the permissions are set up.   I was hoping for an easy way to extract that '90' but looks like I'll need to parse it out.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to get the [SPList.ItemCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.itemcount.aspx) property; that's displayed by the viewlsts.aspx page (as opposed to SPList.Items.Count which will retrieve the list items that the current user has permissions to and then count them).

What's driving this? ie where are you needing to retrieve and use this information?